# ¿Cómo ejecuto "test" en una API?

Tags: nodejs, npm

El archivo package.json está formado por este código:

```
{
  "name": "api.dir.carpeta.test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Unit test for api.dir.carpeta",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "mocha ."
  },
  "keywords": [
    "test"
  ],
  "author": "correo@cominio.com",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws4": "^1.6.0",
    "supertest": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

¿Qué comando ejecuto desde terminal/consola para que se ejecute el test?

Answer (score 2):

Dado que tienes puesto `"start": "mocha ."` con hacer `npm start` se lanzaría dicho script, mas no se funcionara pues no veo la dependencia `mocha` en ese mismo archivo.

Answer (score 0):

Generalmente se usa `npm test` para las pruebas, asi tu package.json te quedaria:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
```